# Treasure from monsters killed by reactive damage such as Fire Shield

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

Do you gain treasure by killing a monster through reactive damage on another player's turn?

The rulebook only says that you may draw a maximum of one treasure per turn when killing a monster, but is not decisive about whether that limit is per player or for the whole group.

During another player's turn a monster was killed and thus he drew a treasure card. Then during his villain phase a monster attacked and hit me, so I chose to use Fire Shield to deal 1 damage in return, which killed the monster.

Would I draw a treasure card because it is the first time I have killed a monster this turn, or would I not gain a treasure because one treasure card has already been drawn this turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this has been open for too long, I'll throw in *my* interpretation of the rules.

I think the first step is to be clear about the *turns*. It seems *you* would be drawing a treasure on *someone else's turn*.

The rules talk about a **Player Turn** (sometimes *Hero's turn*) on page 6. It even singles out how each player's turn is defined by the Hero-Exploration-Villain phases (page 4, under "Taking turns").

This is important because *the other player's turn* is totally independent from *your turn*, so we don't have to take into account your previous actions.

On to the the [ToA rulebook](https://wizkids.com/posters/repository/wizkids/ToA_Rulebook-WEB.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> When **your Hero** defeats a Monster, draw a Treasure card (see 
>   page 13). **You** can only draw one Treasure card *per turn*, no 
>   matter how many Monsters you defeat during *that turn*.

First, I'd rule that your hero has indeed defeated a monster. So we're clear on the first sentence.

As for the second sentence, I'd rule that *you* haven't yet drawn a treasure on *that other player's turn*.

So... use that treasure wisely! ;)